# Tensorflow: different training speed and CPU usage over epochs

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am training a simple Bi-LSTM model on a sentence classification dataset that has about 8000 sentences. I extracted the code snippet about the model and this looks as below. I experienced training slowdown and speedup randomly and inconsistently over different epochs. This is strange as on my local machine or my company server, this **did not happen**, **but on my AWS server**. I wonder what can cause training slowdown randomly during different epochs? I can confirm that there are no other CPU or memory intensive processes running at the same time. My program is the only one.

**Code**:

```
input_shapes=Input(shape=(100, 300))
embedding = Embedding(...)(input_shapes)
lstm = Bidirectional(LSTM(units=100, return_sequences=False))(embedding)
dense = Dense(600)(lstm) 
final = Dense(num_of_classes, activation="softmax")(dense) 
model = Model(inputs=input_shapes, outputs=final)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

training_generator = data_generator(...) #my own method to generate batch on the fly
training_steps_per_epoch = round(len(X_train) / 100
model.fit_generator(training_generator, steps_per_epoch=training_steps_per_epoch, epochs=20)
...
```

**Configuration**:

```
OS: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
CPU: 8 Cores, Mem: 32G
conda 4.4.10
tensorflow 1.10.0
theano 0.9.0
scikit learn 0.19.0
keras 2.0.9
fasttext 0.9.1
nltk 3.2.5 (stopwords, wordnet)
pydot 1.2.3
```

**Observation/Question**: training speed slows down and speeds up randomly over different epochs, during which time different CPU usage is observed. For example, in the epoch that took 60s, I notice that CPU usage is around 300%. But when it took <10s, the CPU usage is 600%. However, as I mentioned above, throughout this time on the AWS server there is no other user-processes at all. My AWS server was created exclusively for this experiment. And this only happens on my AWS server, not on my local machine, or company server. See screenshot of observed time during different epochs

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: As it isnt happening locally, only on AWS it feels like this is one from AWS support. Where is it reading data from? Could there be some kind of bottleneck there that you don't see locally?

Comment: The data is local on the AWS server, presumably on the same node but you never know how the storage is configured physically....